# Using textboxes within userform to define variables?

Tags: vba, excel

I currently run a macro to compare the most recent sheet of data to the report immediately prior and highlight changes. It works fine on its own.  Now, however, we would like to be able to compare selected sheets from any time period.  My idea was to pop up a simple userform with two textboxes that the user can use to specify which two reports he wants to compare.  I am quite lost though with the idea of trying to declare public variables; what I've got atm is:

```
Option Explicit
Public shtNew As String, shtOld As String, _
TextBox1 As TextBox, TextBox2 As TextBox

Sub SComparison()

    Const ID_COL As Integer = 31 'ID is in this column
    Const NUM_COLS As Integer = 31 'how many columns are being compared?

    Dim rwNew As Range, rwOld As Range, f As Range
    Dim X As Integer, Id

    shtNew = CSManager.TextBox1
    shtOld = CSManager.TextBox2

    'Row location of the first employee on "CurrentMaster" sheet
    Set rwNew = shtNew.Rows(5)

    Do While rwNew.Cells(ID_COL).Value <> ""

        Id = rwNew.Cells(ID_COL).Value
        Set f = shtOld.UsedRange.Columns(ID_COL).Find(Id, , xlValues, xlWhole)

        If Not f Is Nothing Then

            Set rwOld = f.EntireRow

            For X = 1 To NUM_COLS
                If rwNew.Cells(X).Value <> rwOld.Cells(X).Value Then
                    rwNew.Cells(X).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                    rwNew.Cells(33) = "UPDATE"
                Else
                    rwNew.Cells(X).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
                End If
            Next X

        End If

        Set rwNew = rwNew.Offset(1, 0) 'next row to compare

        Loop

        Call SUpdates
End Sub
```

Comment: Usually I end up with an invalid qualifier error.

Comment: You have defined `shtNew` and `shtOld` as a string :) See the code that I posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My Suggestion would be to use Comboboxes instead of TextBoxes. Create a userform with two command buttons and two comboboxes and populate the comboboxes in the `UserForm_Initialize()` event using this code.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        ComboBox1.AddItem ws.Name: ComboBox2.AddItem ws.Name
    Next
End Sub
```

And then use this code in the `OK` button to do the comparison.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim shtNew As Worksheet, shtOld As Worksheet

    If ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then
        MsgBox "Please select the first sheet"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If ComboBox2.ListIndex = -1 Then
        MsgBox "Please select the Second sheet"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set shtNew = Sheets(ComboBox1.Value)
    Set shtOld = Sheets(ComboBox2.Value)

    '~~> REST OF THE CODE HERE NOW TO WORK WITH THE ABOVE SHEETS
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

HTH

Sid

Comment: To continue to add to your posts, Sid: Should there also be a check to verify the two selected sheets are not the same (i.e. no reason to compare)?

Comment: On the right track with this, but my primary issue is that it includes all worksheets in the workbook.  There are several templates that I keep veryhidden and several summary sheets that separate out specific information and chart data that I would not want included in the combobox.  Is there a reltively painless way to keep specified sheets from appearing in the combobox?  Aside from that the code you showed works great - I do like the comboboxes - keeps me from having to worry about users entering the wrong information in the textbox.

Comment: @Jon: You can put names of the sheets (which you don't want in an array) and then check for it before adding to the combo :)

Comment: Also, you can check for the visibility and skip if hidden or very hidden.

Comment: @Gaffi: Yes. There are many things that you need to take care of in that code. I am sure Jon will take care of that. The code that I gave is just a basic code which needs to be amended as per specific needs :)

Comment: By george, I think I've got it! Thank you for your assistance Sid.

Answer (score 1):

For an easy fix, couldn't you just colour (sorry, I'm English!) the worksheets that you want to refer to, then do something like:

```
Sub ListSheets()

'lists only non-coloured sheets in immediate window
'(could amend to add to combo boxes)
Dim w As Worksheet

'loop over worksheets in active workbook
For Each w In Worksheets

    If w.Tab.Color Then

        'if tab color is set, print
        Debug.Print w.Name

    End If

Next w
```

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: I went with an array, but I do like the idea of using tab color. I don't usually do that but I like it as an alternative.